# ActionView::Template::Error, multiple unknown regexp options problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, actionview

1 to make an application, and everything's been working fine so far. However, out of nowhere, ActionView is suddenly failing horribly. It seems it can't recognize any closed html tags. Every time it sees a closed parentheses, it claims that these are unclosed. However, they all are! I've posted the error log below, maybe someone knows what's going on. I've also put only part of the log because it's massive.

```
~/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:20: unknown regexp options - pa
unmatched close parenthesis: /div>

        <div class="rhm1-bg">

Extracted source (around line #20):

17:         <ul>
18:       <% if user_signed_in? %>
19:         Signed in as <%= current_user.email %>. Not you?
20:         <li><span><%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></span></li>
21:       <% else %>
22:         <li><span><%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %></span></li>
23:         <li><span><%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %></span></li>
```

But in my HTML file, this div is of course, closed.

**Edit:** it also seems that ActionView is failing on pretty much everything. Anyone know why this would suddenly be happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So in trying to comment out the inclusion of a javascript file, I did

```
<%= #javascript_include_tag "http://localhost:9292/faye.js" %>
```

NOTE the #. That's what was throwing ActionView off.

What it should be:

```
<!--<%= javascript_include_tag "http://localhost:9292/faye.js" %>-->
```

Comment: Great fix!!! Thanks a lot varatis.. I never noticed that and kept blaming deface for doing wrong compilation!